# Send UIImageView back to 1 layer down

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I have a View and its subview is an array of UIImageView (Let's say 5). The sequence of my UIImageView as 1-2-3-4-5.

Understand that if i use `sendSubviewToBack` for 3, the sequence will be 3-1-2-4-5.
How do i send the 3 to one layer down instead of sending it to the most back, eg. (1-3-2-4-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`-exchangeSubviewAtIndex:…`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/exchangeSubviewAtIndex%3awithSubviewAtIndex%3a) to swap the order of the two subviews.

```
[theParentView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:2];
```

'1' is the index of view #2 and '2' is the index of view #3.

Comment: how do i know what is the index?

Comment: @RockBaby: `[theParentView.subviews indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:theSubview]`